# How little space is possible between the stove and the hood

Tags: stove, range, hood

Most of the ranges I look at in the professional area...Wolf, Thermador, Miele etc. mention that 30" is the minimum height from cook top to hood...the space I have currently is about 27 1/2" and I cannot change the height without major construction.  This is for a 30" range and hood (300 CFM)...do you foresee issues with this?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a cooktop that puts out an inordinate amount of heat? The possibility that you melt the plastic parts of the hood would be my biggest concern...

Comment: The same [ventilation guide](https://www.subzero-wolf.com/-/media/files/united-states/product-downloads/sub-zero-wolf/misc/ventilation-guide.pdf) that I linked to on your other question mentions that under-cabinet hoods need to be at least 24" above the range.  So at least Wolf recognizes that less than 30" is acceptable in some cases.

Comment: There could be visibility and accessibility issues if the hood is too low, plus there may be too much heat building up under the hood.

Comment: Gas or Electric?  Gas needs more clearance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more concerned about **maximum** distance to get enough effective airflow. For minimum I'd recommend tallest pot plus 6"-8" so that you can take the lid off and stir without the hood getting in the way.